# Android animation rotate infinite, without pausing

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, rotation, infinite

I can rotate my image infinitely. But my problem is that the image pauses shortly when it reaches 360º and then starts rotating again. It happens the same even when I applied "linear_interpolator".
What I want to do is that the image does not pause at all when it starts the next round. So it has to rotate infinitely with same speed at any degree.

> Here is my - code. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1400"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />
</set>
```

> How I call it on my code

```
    rotate= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.loop_rotate)
    binding.imgSecondLayout.startAnimation(rotate)
```

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)` to your java class where animation is called.

My final code is given here:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.loop_rotate);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
animation.setDuration(1400);
youractivity.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your code! I applied it on mine and it finally works! This really made my day! Thanks

Comment: Happy to help always ☺️

Comment: So, setting the attributes again programatically worked ??

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo Yes, it worked , I also tried it with the code given in the question

Comment: @Sayooj I just did!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the small delay after the animation completes its duration (1400 ms in ur case). you can remove this delay for smooth animation.

Remove repeatMode attribute and instead add this line :

```
android:startOffset="0"  //Delay in milliseconds before the animation runs
```

The animation will be smooth without any delays

Comment: This solution didn't work for me but I solved it now anyways. Thanks a lot, tho!

Comment: @Lucy so what was causing the problem ??

Comment: It's not clear.... I applied both of { android:startOffset="0" } and linearInterpolator on my XML before posting a question here but it didn't work out. I finally could make it when I wrote linearInterpolator on the code file.

Comment: strange, i didn't need to set any attribute programatically, mine just worked fine with just the xml code.

Answer (score 0):

your question asking took approximately 1 year and now i faced to the same problem but the checked answer did not work for me

instead I add this line to my animation set tag in xml :

```
android:shareInterpolator="false"
```

and my xml animation is like below now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">


    <rotate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```